# 'engaged in developing' or 'engaged in the development of'?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, gerunds

> XXX is engaged in **developing** and **commercializing** therapies for the treatment of Alzheimer's patients.

or

> XXX is engaged in the **development** and **commercialization** of therapies for the treatment of cancer patients.

I want to know which one of these sentences is grammatically correct, pertaining to the use of a continuous verb after *engaged in*.

Is there a difference between the two sentences?

Comment: I can't decide what tags to apply to this post. Someone could help.

Answer (score 2):

They are both grammatical. Both are symantically equivalent or at least similar (broadly mean the same thing).

An important point to note is that the *-ing* forms here are not 'continuous verbs' as such, they are 'gerunds', which behave like nouns. As such, using a gerund is equivalent to using a noun, as far as grammar is concerned. Technically, there's no grammatical difference.

Answer (score 0):

I know both are correct. However, I face another question in this example. @Kris

Longman dictionary says "engage" means "*to be doing or to become involved in an activity*" and it is "*intransitive always + preposition*" for this meaning. Longman dictionary also offers collocations under this entry.

One is "engage in/on/upon" and the other is "engage in doing something". Its example of the second on is, *Despite her illness, she remains actively engaged in shaping policy.*

In this sentence, is *engage(d)* still a verb? If yes, being an intransitive verb (in this entry "to be doing or to become involved in an activity), it should not have a passive voice?

If no, it has to be regarded as an adjective; however, I cannot find a suitable meaning of *engaged* (adjective). Longman dictionary offers four meanings. They are, people agree to marry, telephone line is busy, public toilet being used and be unable to do sth because you are doing sth else (be otherwise engaged).

In summary, I am unable to explain what role the word "engage(d)" plays in the sentence of *Despite her illness, she remains actively engaged in shaping policy.*

Comment: Please post a separate question. Good Luck.